# Maximization of quadratic form on a sphere

Tags: optimization, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, quadratic-forms

I have to following problem
$$\max_{x}x^TAx+b^Tx\quad \mathrm{s.t.}\quad  x^Tx\leq c,$$
where $A$ is real, symmetric and positive semi-definite.

Firstly I tried to solve the problem with the KKT, but that didn't lead to any good results for arbitrary matrices.

So now I argue in the following way

Since $x^TAx \leq \lambda_{max}x^Tx$, I get $x^TAx+b^Tx\leq \lambda_{max}x^Tx + b^Tx$ and with the constraint $x^Tx\leq c$ this leads to
$$x^TAx+b^Tx\leq \lambda_{max}x^Tx + b^Tx \leq \lambda_{max}c+b^Tx$$
So my solution would be
$$x=\sqrt{c}v_{max},$$
where $v_{max}$ is the unit-eigenvector corresponding to the largest eigenvalue $\lambda_{max}$ of $A$.
The thing that confuses me about this solution is that the solution does not depend on $b$ at all, so I am sure it is not correct...

Comment: @Rahul Thanks for the hint to this questions. I would still like to know, why my solution is not correct then.

Comment: From $x^TAx+b^Tx\le \lambda_{\max}c+b^Tx$ how do you conclude that the optimum is $x=\sqrt cv_{\max}$?

Comment: To get an equality instead of inequality, but I see your point. So I really have to go with the KKT conditions..
Thanks though!